# Questions are no longer being accepted

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Right now Information Security is no longer accepting questions from my account. Is there a way to override this or am I screwed?

Comment: Crosspost of https://meta.superuser.com/q/13308/247927

Comment: Your account is new. What do you think could be the cause of this ban? Have you performed any actions which could have led to that?

Answer (score 7):

Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

The greatest emphasis:

> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.